# how to apply coupan code in magento without reloading whole page using AJAX

Tags: ajax, magento-1.9

Hello I am using Magento 1.9 I want to apply coupon code programmatically when user group is wholesaler without reloading cart page I want to dynamically update only grand total when coupon code is applied

thanks in adavance.

Comment: could you provide some code as to what you have tried, and be a bit more specific on where you are getting stuck?

Comment: @Bill we check whether the user is wholesaler at the time of checkout i.e proceed to checkout & we get a particular response ... if the person is valid wholesaler than discount must be applied without reloading the page & must take to billing page because we check the validation of user on that particular page i.e cart page which contains discount coupon view & validation of the user .